# Configuring CloudSQL (MySQL) with binary logs but without backups

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql

In the Google CloudSQL (MySQL) console, I can read:

> Automated backups required for binary logging.

This requirement looks strange to me.  I do not understand why automated backups are required for binary logging.  I see use-cases where I might want replication (and failover, both needing binary logging) without automated backups.

Does anyone know why this requirement exists ?

Comment: Perhaps the sentence is backward:  "Binary logging is required for automated backups."

Comment: Yes, maybe it is backward, and then it would be an interesting bugas it is possible to "Enable Backups" without binary logging in CloudSQL.